# how to check the process is running or not - Linux

Tags: linux, shell, sockets, embedded-linux

I am invoking a binary file using shell script. Binary file is basically establish a socket client server. this binary works fine initially but after 60mints its is getting stop. I need to check if it is not running then start it again. here is my code :

```
sleep 3
busyboxValue=busybox
commandpid=`$busyboxValue pidof command`
echo ${commandpid} > /sdcard/CommandProcess.txt
if [ $commandpid -gt 0 ]
then
    echo -16 > /proc/$commandpid/oom_adj
    echo -1000 > /proc/$commandpid/oom_score_adj
fi
while [ true ]
do
    commandpid=`$busyboxValue pidof command`
    if [ $commandpid -gt 0 ]
    then
        echo "command binary still running"
    else
        echo "command binary Exited so restarting it"
        /data/local/command 1200 &
        commandpid=`$busyboxValue pidof command`
        echo ${commandpid} > /sdcard/CommandProcess.txt
        echo -16 > /proc/$commandpid/oom_adj
        echo -1000 > /proc/$commandpid/oom_score_adj
    fi
    sleep 10
done
```

Comment: Is there a question here? Are you looking for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: He's asking how to create a watchdog to start his thing and re-start it if it dies

Comment: `its is getting stop` Do you mean it's receiving a SIGSTOP and entering the "stopped" state? ... or is it stalled? ... or is it terminated?

Comment: it is terminated. i can not see when i am using ps command

Answer (score 0):

You can use the python supervisor utility, which will take care of re-starting a dead program for you.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/supervisor